# Marginalization in gaussian

Tags: calculus

If $\theta\mid\mu \sim N(\mu,\sigma_o^2)$ and $\mu \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$ what is the marginalized $P(\theta)$.

$\theta$ and $\mu$ both are $n\times 1$ vectors

$P(\theta) = \int P(\theta\mid\mu)P(\mu)\,d\mu$

Is it $N(0,\sigma_o^2I+\sigma_1^2A)$?

where $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix with all ones?

Comment: It $\mu\in\mathbb R^{n\times 1}\sim N$ then the variance of $\mu$ is an $n\times n$ nonnegative-definite matrix.

Comment: Why do you expect that it isn't $N(0,\sigma_0^2 + \sigma_1^2)$?

Comment: @EricTowers - Sorry I didn't see you're comment when I wrote my answer, I probably didn't need to repeat :P

Answer (score 0):

We can write $N(\mu | \sigma_0^2) = N(0 | \sigma_0^2) + \mu$, in other words creating a zero mean probability distribution. But $\mu = N(0 | \sigma_1^2)$, so we can say $N(\mu | \sigma_0^2) = N(0 | \sigma_0^2) + N(0 | \sigma_1^2)$. The sum of two zero mean gaussian distributions $N(\mu | \sigma_0^2) = N(0 | \sigma_0^2 + \sigma_1^2)$

[Click here for more details about the sum of normal distributions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalSumDistribution.html)